# How to get the .47 file from ORCA for natural bonding orbital analysis

Tags: quantum-chemistry, software-assistance, orca, orbitals, population-analysis

I am trying to perform NBO analysis with relaxed density matrix with the open-source program JANPA. I am following the guide [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/janpa/wiki/OrcaExamples/). The first step is to get the NBO input .47 file from Orca v4.2.1. The guide says that I should request NBO analysis with Orca in absence of the actual NBO executable to get the .47 file.

So I set the GENEXE and NBOEXE environment variables to dummy exe files that don't do anything when called. However, in spite of this, I cannot see the .47 file anywhere on the disk.

How do I generate the file required for NBO analysis? Any help is appreciated.

**Edit**: The input file I am using is:

```
! RHF SP def2-SVP NPA 

* xyz 0 1
   C       -1.54056        0.93336        0.00000
   H       -0.47056        0.93336        0.00000
   H       -1.89722       -0.02889       -0.30294
   H       -1.89722        1.67683       -0.68186
   H       -1.89723        1.15213        0.98480
*
```

I am setting the environment variables with

```
set GENEXE=C:\Users\Public\Orca4.1\orca\gennbo.exe
set NBOEXE=C:\Users\Public\Orca4.1\orca\nbo6.exe
```

Both nbo6.exe and gennbo.exe are dummy executables that don't do anything when executed.
Note that the Orca version is 4.2.1 even though the directory name is 4.1.

Comment: Can we see the input file you are using? You don't even necessarily have to include the geometry, just the keywords for the calculation. Also, your tutorial and the [ORCA manual](https://www.afs.enea.it/software/orca/orca_manual_4_2_1.pdf) suggest its behavior with NBOs differs by version, so you should include the version of ORCA you are using.

Comment: @Tyberius Added input file and orca version.

Answer (score 7):

All files are always created in the run directory where ORCA runs.
I specifically did not want to deal with environment variables and path names and all that.
Hope that helps!
best wishes,
Frank Neese

Comment: Thanks!! I never expected the author of Orca himself to answer, this is quite helpful. I am running orca with orca.exe input.inp > output.out, but I can't see any .47 file being created in the directory. Is there any command line arguments that I need?